# How to get specific attribute value with XDocument

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have this xml
[image]

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<model xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" identifier="id- 
5f3a493ba7067b8a30bfbf6b" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengroup.org/xsd/archimate/3.0/">
<name xml:lang="EN"></name>
<views>
<diagrams>
  <view identifier="id-4bad55d7-9619-4f21-bcc2-47ddb19d57b3">
      <name xml:lang="EN">1shape</name>
    <node xmlns:q1="" xsi:type="q1:Shape" identifier="id-97d9fcda-f478-4564-9abd-e2f544d2e292" x="10" y="30" w="1" h="1" nameinternal="BD_shapes_av_Square" shapeId="5bc59d14ec9d2633e8ea102e" angle="0" isgroup="False" alignment="" textalign="0" size="696 360">
      <label xml:lang="EN" />
      <style>
        <fillColor r="102" g="170" b="215" />
        <font name="Lato" size="13">
          <color r="255" g="255" b="255" />
        </font>
      </style>
    </node>
    <node xmlns:q2="" xsi:type="q2:Shape" identifier="id-3b754535-530f-49d2-9e7b-113df0659af9" x="226" y="114" w="1" h="1" nameinternal="BD_shapes_av_Coffee" shapeId="5dad5a884527ecc5c8c4871b" angle="0" isgroup="False" alignment="" textalign="0" size="52.3 72">
      <label xml:lang="EN" />
      <style>
        <fillColor r="102" g="45" b="145" />
        <font name="Lato" size="13">
          <color r="255" g="255" b="255" />
        </font>
      </style>
    </node>
  </view>
</diagrams>
```

I need to check if the node xsi:type attribute value is Shape or not.
I have the xml loaded in XDocument
I've tried to get to the node element

```
 xDocument.Descendants("views").Attributes("xsi:type");
```

If I use

```
xDocument.Root.Element("views"); - it returns null
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a minimal example with the XML as *text* rather than an image. My guess is that this is a namespace issue, but we can't tell because the XML is cropped.

Comment: That's neither a minimal example nor complete - while it *is* enough for me to answer the question (which I'm doing now) it would be really handy if in future questions you provided a [mcve]. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. Firstly, you're currently looking for an element called `views` which isn't in an XML namespace.

Your XML doesn't contain any such elements - this part of your root element:

```
xmlns="http://www.opengroup.org/xsd/archimate/3.0/"
```

... means that that's the default namespace for descendants, including `views`.

Fortunately LINQ to XML makes it very easy to work with namespaces. You just need:

```cs
XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengroup.org/xsd/archimate/3.0/";
XElement views = xDocument.Root.Element(ns + "views");
```

However, that doesn't have any attributes on it. It looks like you're really trying to find the attributes of the *node* elements. Again, you'd want to get the namespaces right too:

```cs
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
var attributes = views.Descendants(ns + "node").Attributes(xsi + "type");
```

Or iterating over the nodes and checking the values:

```cs
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
foreach (var node in views.Descendants(ns + "node"))
{
    var type = (string) node.Attribute(xsi + "type");
    if (type is string && type.EndsWith(":Shape"))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```